# How to communicate with client manager in an effective way?

Tags: professionalism, communication

Recently one of my colleagues has joined in my account. The project manager has yet to introduce this colleague to the client, and all communication between my colleague and our client is done through email.

This colleague hasn't gotten a response from our client, and as consequence, hasn't been assigned to a project. This is in spite of his experience, and may emails attempting to find out what project he will be working on. He has tried to ping client manager directly, but received no response.  He has even scheduled couple of meetings, but this also resulted in silence.

How should we handle this situation?

Comment: So he is asking client what work should he do?

Comment: Yeah.  He just want to know what project is being assigned to him.

Comment: Wouldn't project manager would be able to tell him that? Since that's the job of project manager, to manage the projects.

Comment: How is **your** communication with the client? Are the manager and your colleague trying to push you out?

Comment: No.  He is off-shore manager and doesn't involve in these things.  Only thing what he does is just share resume to onsite and taking care of billing activities.

Comment: I think question is a bit ambiguous try to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly how the relationship between your company and the client company is structured, it's clear that you need to appeal to a higher authority for assistance. Communication requesting clarity around their assignment, and meetings, should be CC'd to someone who has **clear authority** over these things on *your* side of the table.

A word of caution about spamming a client company about what what work they want you to do though. This can end of angering the client because you've turned from an eager and excited provider in to a pest.

Answer (score 0):

From the client's point of view, they are receiving communication and requests from an unknown person which is likely why they have been silent.

If the normal procedure is for the project manager to introduce any new members to the client then it should be followed.  Your colleague needs to reach out to the project manager and ask to be formally introduced to the client.